# StreamReader.ReadToEnd reading differently second time around

Tags: c#, stream, streamreader

I need to read from the same stream twice. The problem is i get a different string the second time. 
Here is the shortened code:

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    string string1  = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
    sr.DiscardBufferedData();   
    string string2 = sr.ReadToEnd();
    bool sameSame = string1 == string2; // false!
}
```

The strings look the same but checking with a hex editor i can see that the values are different. What is causing this and how do i get around it?

**UPDATE**

string1

[image: string1]

string2

[image: string2]

For some reason string1 has a '--'.

Comment: What do you mean: "checking with a hex editor"?

Comment: What difference you see? Length? Contents?

Comment: I compared string1 and string2 at http://www.edithex.com/. The characters produced different hex values.

Comment: Where does it show differences? I wonder if this is BOM-related... Also; was the stream at the start initially? Note: you should avoid the *need* to re-read a stream.

Comment: Does "--" mean "00" in that tool?

Comment: Yes, it is a BOM related problem, you get if your file starts with EF BB BF.

Comment: @Marc I need to read the stream to a string before serializing it with XmlSerializer. When passing the fresh stream to the serializer everything works but not after reading to string. Sorry, I don't know what '--' means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with the byte order mark, a dirty workaround would be to skip the first three bytes:

```
sr.BaseStream.Position = 3;
```

But the proper way is to create a new StreamReader.

Comment: IMHO the byte order mark can have different length in different encodings. Also, I think it is two bytes long?

Comment: It depends on the encoding. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding

Comment: Well, that's why I called it 'dirty'. Hopefully, Malako went with the second option...